# codepen - Plus In Missing?

Tags: javascript, html

I found  [this in Codepen](http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/GAIkt) and I copy all the code to make my local page, it doesn't work as expect.  Do I miss something like a plus in?

Comment: what error's you are getting int the console..?

Comment: This codepen is popup samples, but when I make my local page, the popups don't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to download all the files from `Codepen` to your computer and check to see what specific codes or which files you're currently missing.

To download a pen from `Codepen` you can click on `Share` button located at the top bar and choose `Export.zip`.

Comment: Thank you, Felix.  Doing as your direction, I see I miss some JQuery plusins